# Upload from VMware Workstation 10 to ESXi 5.1 fails consistently with `Upload failed: Execution aborted.`

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-workstation

Situation:

- VMware Workstation 10 on Windows 8.1
- ESXi 5.1 on HP XW6600
- Connecting by IPv4 IP address (i.e. no DNS resolution is used)
- Both connected to the same physical Gigabit router
- Just succesfully pumped close to 800 gigabytes from ESXi 4.1 machines connected to the same Gigabit router using Veeam FastSCP to this ESXi 5.1 machine
- VM was created using VMware Workstation 8, but runs fine on this VMware Workstation 10 machine
- VM was shut down before the transfer
- I'm transferring using drag/drop
- I can manage the existing VMs that run on the ESXi 5.1 box from VMware Workstation 10 fine.

After the upload is almost completed, it fails consistently with this error message:

```
---------------------------
VMware Workstation
---------------------------
Upload failed: Execution aborted.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

During the upload, both the network and disk performance graph is on a consistent level (no big peaks or big lows).

No other big activity on the ESXi 5.1 and VMware Workstation machine, nor on the network.

Where should I start researching after these result no useful information:

- No search results for ["VMware workstation" "Upload failed: Execution aborted."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22VMware%20workstation%22%20%22Upload%20failed:%20Execution%20aborted.%22)
- No relevant results for [VMware "Upload failed: Execution aborted."](https://www.google.com/search?q=VMware%20%22Upload%20failed:%20Execution%20aborted.%22)